# handling $http.get and $http.post errors in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, post, get

Folks,

I am using `$http.get` and `$http.post` all over my code. I am kind of lost as to how to handle errors that occur during these calls in a global fashion. 
Currently I have `.success(doSomething).error(doSomething)` on every call.

I would like to change this and instead simply display the error on top of my page.

I read about using interceptors with `myapp.something`. But I absolutely do not understand how to implement this.

Kindly assist

Answer (score 6):

Response interceptors are attached during the config phase of an angularjs app. You can use them to globally respond to any $http request. Be aware, template files also use $http request, so you may wish to filter some requests in your interceptor to only the ones you wish to respond to.

A good understanding of the [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) pattern is needed to successfully use response interceptors.

Heres an example of how they are used:

```
angular.module('services')
    .config(function($httpProvider){
        //Here we're adding our interceptor.
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('globalInterceptor');
    })
    //Here we define our interceptor
    .factory('globalInterceptor', function($q){
        //When the interceptor runs, it is passed a promise object
        return function(promise){

            //In an interceptor, we return another promise created by the .then function.
            return promise.then(function(response){
                //Do your code here if the response was successful

                //Always be sure to return a response for your application code to react to as well
                return response;
            }, function(response){
                //Do your error handling code here if the response was unsuccessful

                //Be sure to return a reject if you cannot recover from the error somehow.
                //This way, the consumer of the $http request will know its an error as well
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: ATTENTION!! This method has been deprecated. Follow this link for the alternative, http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http