# Exception Handling In Angularjs HTTP Methods

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to angularjs. I am using angularjs 1.4 version. I am attempting to handle exception which is throwing from Spring controller method.
But i could not able to catch the exception in below js below.

May be this is duplicate question, but i had searched solution in SO. But did not work. Please give me suggestion for this. Thanks in advance.

Also throwing exceptions in Spring MVC controller method is correct? or how to say 500 error to front end?

In Angular Controller:

```
Service.calculate (obj).then(function(response){
    // logic
});
```

In Angular Service:

```
this.calculate = function(obj){
     try {
         return $http.post(PATH+'txn/calc',obj).then(function(resp){
                 return resp;
         }); 
     } catch (e) {
         alert(e);
     }
 };
```

Spring controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/txn/calc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody someBean calculate(@RequestBody SomeBean someBean , HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        // exception occurs here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687804/handling-http-get-and-http-post-errors-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$http.post(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log('post',response)
},
function(data) {
    // Handle error here
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But It is not coming to function(data) block its coming to function(response) block. But it is coming in spring controller catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a function as a second parameter for the then function like this:

```
$http.post(url).then(
function(response) {
  console.log(response);
},
function(data) {
  // Handle error here
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But It is not coming to function(data) block. But it is coming in spring controller catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You don't must to use Try Catch in your javascript function. You need to use catch function from your promise.

```
this.calculate = function(obj){
         return $http.post(PATH+'txn/calc',obj).then(function(resp){
             return resp;
          }).catch(function(error){ alert(error) }; 

 };
```

The best pratice is to use a services or factory for return a promise. And you apply your then and catch function in your service.

```
app.factory('myService',myService);
myService.$inject('$http');
function myService($http){ 
     var services = { 
         calculate:calculate 
     } 
     return services; 

     function calculate(obj){ 
         return $http.post(PATH+'txn/calc',obj) 
     } 
}
```

After you inject your services or factory in your controller and you call your function from this.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','myService'];
function myCtrl($scope,myService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.calculate = function(obj){
        myService.then(success).catch(error);

        function success(response){...}
        function error(response){...}
     }
}
```

Comment: nevradub thanks, but it says catch invalid identifier in angular contoller

Comment: So try to use two callback in your function then. (.then(successCallback, errorCallback))

Comment: nevradub. You mean then should have 2 parameters.

Comment: Yest, in classic method the first parameter is a success callback and the second parameter is a error callback. Look the official document for more precision if you need. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Ok thanks nevradub. when i use two callback functions, its going first block i mean success block instead of error block. do you know why.

Comment: Strange are you sure your server return status code 500 ?

Comment: throwing exception in spring controller catch block is right? or should i do something else. how to check status code in angularjs. sorry for asking like this.

Comment: I don't knwo in java, but in .NET i don't use try catch. If i need to throw an exeption i use throw new Exeption("my message") instead of try catch. I use try catch if i need to apply a logic when there is error. If you need just throw an exeption try to use throw new Exeption(). So warning, when you use angular js you need to specified ==> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; in your config function. (in .NET, i don't know if you need to specified this in java).

Comment: Ok nevradub, i put alert (resp.status). its returns 200. i think problem in server side.

Comment: I thinks to. Because when you use try catch block in server side the exeption is managed so the server side not return error 500. Try to use just throw new Exeption("message").

Comment: But even though i am throwing exception in catch block. really i am confused. let me try.